# How can I use twitter provider in cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter

I'd like our users to signin with their twitter authentication and I have read this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-twitter-and-digits-support-for-amazon-cognito/ which says they support twitter authentication natively. However, I can't find that in uesr-pool federation provider on AWS. Below is a screenshot about all providers I can use. So how can I setup twitter provier?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There has never been twitter support in Cognito *user pools* (only in *identity pools*). https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-twitter-and-digits-support-for-amazon-cognito/ - this link only shows steps for identity pools and not user pools.